# barplot in R using different classes

Tags: r

I have this example in R:

```
 mat2
 ##        Bos_RM   Bos_SM Jac_AGM Jac_RM
 ## t34340 22.67389    NA     14   19.60895
 ## t60337 18.00000  12.0     NA   19.60895
 ## t71357 22.67389   9.5     11   19.60895

bar = barplot2(t(mat2), 
         beside = TRUE,
         col = c("red","green","blue","orange"),
         # legend = colnames(mat2), 
         ylim = c(0, max(na.omit(mat2))+1),
         ylab="-logpvalue",
         #xaxt='n',
         #xlab="",
         )
box()
```

Producing this figure:

[image: descricao da imagem]

I would like to produce this figure without these space (created by `NA`s).

Comment: figure isn't showing up and a `dput(mat2)` would be helpful.

Comment: added the plot for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `ggplot2`, this will do it for you:

```
mat2 <- read.table(textConnection("Bos_RM   Bos_SM Jac_AGM Jac_RM
t34340 22.67389    NA     14   19.60895
t60337 18.00000  12.0     NA   19.60895
t71357 22.67389   9.5     11   19.60895"))

# convert transpose to data frame
dat <- data.frame(t(mat2))
dat$b <- rownames(dat)
rownames(dat) <- NULL

# melt the data for ggplot2 plot
q <- melt(dat)

# plot only the bars that aren't NA
gg <- ggplot(na.omit(q), aes(x=variable, y=value, group=b))
gg <- gg + geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=b), position="dodge")
gg <- gg + labs(x="", y="-logpvalue", title="")
gg
```

Change `b` to whatever makes sense for the plot.

[image]

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to consider the names on the x-axis closer to bars and  those names appear separately for each group? Best,

Comment: Trying to figure out what you need. So you want to remove the whitespace between "t34340", etc? Also, you want the "Bos…" and "Jac…" labels on the bars?

Comment: Hi thanks to reply me. yes in first case (remove or reduce the space). In the second case, is put the stick in x axis indicading each group (group t34340, group t60337, t71357) separately (or maybe to remove the line). This is because in fact I have a lot of groups...best wishes

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base solution:

```
v <- as.vector(t(mat2))
bar = barplot(v, 
         beside = TRUE, 
         width = as.integer(!is.na(v)), # set widths based on missingness
         space = rep(c(1,0,0,0),3), # manually set spacing
         col = c("red","green","blue","orange"),
         ylim = c(0, max(na.omit(mat2))+1),
         ylab="-logpvalue"
         )
```

[image]